# tensorflow unique function with 2d?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow1.15

`tf.unique` currently only works on 1D tensors. How can I find index of unique values in a 2D tensor.

```
input = tf.constant([[0,0,1,1,1,8], [2,2,5,5,5,2], [6,6,6,8,8,9]])
#output should be  = [[0,0,1,1,1,2], [0,0,1,1,1,0], [0,0,0,1,1,2]]
```

Comment: Try: `indices = tf.vectorized_map(lambda a: tf.unique(a).idx, x)` where `x` is your input. And if possible, upgrade your tensorflow version.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over 1D tensors that made up your 2D tensor to get all the indices of the unique values:

```py
indices = []

for value in input:
   idx = tf.unique(value).idx
   indices.append(idx)

print(indices)
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2])>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2])>]
```

Lastly, if you need to you can `tf.concat(indices, axis=0)` or `tf.stack(indices)` them.